# Mongodb - unknown top level operator: $elemMatch"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection which contains some documents as follows,

```
{
  "transactionId": 3432423,
  "reviews": [
    {
      "fromUser": {
        "userId": "5236aa1acd6e"
      },
      "toUser": {
        "userId": "0ec8db9544cc"
      },
      "rating": 4.3,
      "comment": ""
    },
    {
    "toUser": {
        "userId": "5236aa1acd6e",
        "email": "yourlife@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "your",
        "lastName": "life"
      },
      "fromUser": {
        "userId": "0ec8db9544cc",
        "email": "mylife@gmail.com",
        "firstName": "my",
        "lastName": "life"
      },
      "rating": 4.3,
      "comment": ""
    }
  ]

}
```

i need to check if subdocument reviews present inside the document. i have used this query,

```
db.getCollection('_testCollection').find({  "$elemMatch": { "reviews": { "$exists": false } }})
```

it throws an error saying,

```
"errmsg" : "unknown top level operator: $elemMatch",
```

Comment: which version of mongodb you are using

Comment: version is 3.2.12

Comment: `db.getCollection('_testCollection').find({ "reviews" : { "$elemMatch": { "$exists": false } }})`
It must be like this way because reviews is key.
for finding in array @JohnnyHK  is right. You dont need to use $elemMatch.

Comment: @JohnnyHK it does not return any results. i have a doc wiht reviews:[] . it does not retun that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither `$elemMatch` or `$exists` is what you want to use to determine if `reviews` is an empty array.

Instead, either compare against `[]`:

```
db.test.find({reviews: []})
```

Or use the `$size` operator:

```
db.test.find({reviews: {$size: 0}})
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs :-

The **$elemMatch** operator matches documents that contain an array field with at least one element that matches all the specified query criteria.

```
db.getCollection('_testCollection').find({  "reviews": {"$elemMatch" : { "$exists": false } }})
```

$exists :- true or false // depend on requirement

Thanks